# Incorrect random number - Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to take random username and password from an array, and checking whether current username password is same as previous username password. If it is same, i want to take different user id, pass from the array. I wrote below code, but I it also picks up same username passwords.

```js
let usernames = ["uname1", "uname2"],
        passwords = ["pass1", "pass1"];

    let rand, prevRand;
    prevRand = _.random(0, usernames.length - 1);
    rand = _.random(0, usernames.length - 1);

    console.log("rand " + rand)
    console.log("prevrand " + prevRand)


    if (rand !== prevRand) {
        console.log("uname!==: " + usernames[rand])
        console.log("pass!==: " + passwords[rand])
        prevRand = rand;
    } else {
        while (rand !== prevRand) {
            rand = _.random(0, usernames.length - 1);
            console.log("newrand " + rand)

        }
        prevRand = rand;
        console.log("unamenew " + usernames[rand])
        console.log("passnew " + passwords[rand])

    }
```

Please correct my logic here..Thanks.

Comment: Please add the lodash or underscorejs tag to indicate which library you're using.

Comment: `while (rand !== prevRand) {` should be `while (rand == prevRand) {`. The way you wrote it forces `rand` to be the same as `prevRand` when the loop finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while (rand !== prevRand)` loop is never executed because it is inside the `else` statement wich means that `rand == prevRand`. Try changing the `while` loop to `do..while`.

Check the example (I've replaced `_.random` with `Math.random` to run without external libraries)

```js
let usernames = ["uname1", "uname2", "uname3", "uname4"],
    passwords = ["passw1", "passw2", "passw3", "passw4"];

let rand, prevRand;
prevRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (usernames.length));
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (usernames.length));

console.log("rand " + rand)
console.log("prevrand " + prevRand)


if (rand !== prevRand) {
    console.log("uname " + usernames[rand])
    console.log("pass " + passwords[rand])
    prevRand = rand;
} else {
    do {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (usernames.length));
        console.log("newrand " + rand)
    } while (rand == prevRand);
    prevRand = rand;
    console.log("unamenew " + usernames[rand])
    console.log("passnew " + passwords[rand])
}
```

Comment: So after making the changes you said, after the if/else loop, if I use the value of rand to get the username in another variable it will be correct?

Comment: @AforApple After the loop `rand` will hold other value than `prevRand`, so `usernames[rand]` will differ from `usernames[prevRand]`. As well as passwords

Answer (score 0):

rand === prevRand is true in the **else** case, so it will never enter the **while** cycle.

The cycle, instead, must loop while rand is equal to prevRand

```
  while (rand === prevRand) {
        rand = _.random(0, usernames.length - 1);
        console.log("newrand " + rand)
 }
```

Each time they are equal a new value to ***rand*** should be given, so they can be different.

Comment: So after making the changes you said, after the if/else loop, if I use the value of rand to get the username in another variable it will be correct?